# WPF: Change the text of menuitem on context menu

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, menuitem, routed-commands

I have `ContextMenu` in XAML with the following `MenuItem`:

```
<MenuItem  Command="local:MyClass.MyCommand" "/>
```

I'd like to change the `Header` of `MenuItem` by somehow changing the `Text` of `RoutedCommand`. And I'd like to do that in `CanExecuteRoutedEventHanlder`. If I just change the `RoutedCommand` `Text`, `MenuItem`s don't get updated, I assume that is because the menu is already created when `CanExecuteRoutedEventHanlder` is run.

Basically I need a method to force update from `Command` to `MenuItem.`

Answer (score 1):

Make your own command:

```
 public class MyCommandClass : ICommand, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public MyCommandClass(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        this.Text = "changed the text";
        PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Then in xaml bind the Header to the MyCommandClass's Text property.